# why there is Brown colour before the voilet ? is this indicate that Brown colour have less wavelength than Voilet?

Tags: spectroscopy

[image]
When I was going somewhere I found this spectrum on Road and we know that it form due to petrol or gasoline drop on road and after that rain come down and form this spectrum. So is there exist Brown on the edge of this spectrum?? BVIBGYOR.» Brown,Violet,Indigo,Blue,Green,Yellow, Orange,Red.

Answer (score 0):

What you are seeing in the brown is red from the next order but faint and mixed with the black road surface.

Comment: How can red be at the edge?

Comment: The red->green->blue sequence repeats as you get multiple wavelngthh differences, until the light is too faint to see

Comment: Brown is a product of the way the human vision system processes the tri-color signals from the eyes, not a single wavelength.